# Can UWP mediaplayer read metadata from the audio streaming server?

Tags: uwp, metadata, media-player, media

I'm developing an app for UWP. The app needs to have a streaming audio player. I make use of UWP mediaplayer. I have manage to play audio streaming and I need to get the song metadata - Artist, Title, Album etc.

Does  UWP mediaplayer can read metadata from the server?

Comment: What's the streaming you are using? HLS or DASH?

Comment: Actually I don't want to build the app to accept only a specific type of streaming. I want to support as many streaming types is possible. The streaming URL will be retrieved from a control panel through INTERNET.  You mean that MediaPlayer supports metadata only for HLS or DASH? Thanks

Comment: MediaPlayer only supports two streaming type: HLS and DASH. And I Know it supports metadata for HLS. I'm not familiar with DASH, don't know how to deal with DASH.

Comment: OK Great. I will appreciate if you give me an example of metadata reading even for HLS. Thanks